# Python: reads CSV properly if CSV generated by human, but not if generated by python

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files that appear to be identical.  One had its values typed in by me, and the other had them written in by Python.  Python is able to find values in the CSV that I wrote, but cannot find them in the CSV that it wrote.

The CSVs look like this:

```
line1: <blank>
line2: 0
line3: 1
```

Here's what I'm using to write the CSV, where ID is a list that I've already filled:

```
myfile = open("Unused IDs.csv", 'ab')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(ID)
```

Here's what I'm using to search the CSV:

```
query = 1
isThere = False 

try:
    with open('Unused IDs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        my_content = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in my_content:
            Row = int(row[0])
            if Row == query:
                isThere = True
except IndexError:
    pass
```

As I said, the funny thing is that isThere evaluates to True when I use the CSV that I entered manually.

Notes:

1. I am very much a beginner with Python.
2. Possibly relevant: "Unused IDs.csv" is written by the same script as the reader.  The first time it is run, it appends new IDs to the CSV.  The second time it is run, it first checks the CSV to see if those IDs were already written.

For the Python generated CSV,

```
>>> print repr(open('Unused IDs.csv', 'rb').read())
'\r\n"0"\n"1"\n'
```

For the 'Human' generated CSV,

```
>>> print repr(open('Unused IDs.csv', 'rb').read())
'0\r\n1\r\n'
```

Comment: Note that your choosen `delimiter` value is already the default. There is little point in setting the `lineterminator` value for the reader, it ignores that setting.

Comment: And could you include the output of `print repr(open('Unused IDs.csv', 'rb').read())` in your post? That'll tell us *much more* about what is actually in your file.

Comment: I was under the impression that if you use `csv.reader` on a file, you had to set `newline=''` -- is that not true?

Comment: @adsmith: In Python 3, yes, in Python 2, no, you read in binary mode instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! Every time I feel like I have a good grasp of the language I realize there's some fundamental gap in my knowledge. It's good to always have something new to learn!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks so much for your tips!  I've removed the delimiter and lineterminator settings.  I updated my post with the output you asked for (it's '\r\n"0"\n"1"\n').  I tried changing the open setting to 'ab' but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: @user3298333: Note the inconsistent line terminations. What does your 'handmade' CSV look like when given the same `repr()` treatment? Add both to your post (so you or I can format the representations properly).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Added! Thanks again for continuing to help.  I'm learning a lot here.

Comment: Your code gives me a `IndexError: list index out of range` exception for your 'Python produced' file, because you have an empty line in the file. Did you really mean to append, or would simply writing a new, blank file do?

Comment: Ah! Was that `try` / `except IndexError` there to begin with? Because that is why you are not reading the file, you are *bailing out* before second row is read.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I was only posting a snippet of my entire code, which is quite long.  I should have included the exception handling bit here.  Would it be better for me to post the entire code?

Comment: No, I've seen the problem now, it's that exception handler. Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Oh, progress!  Well, I think append is the right thing to be doing here.  What I want is a script that calls an API to look up people's ID numbers.  Since I can only make so many API calls per day, I want to save them by not asking the API for IDs that I know to be unused.  So before I ask the API, I check my CSV.  If an ID that's not in the CSV turns out to be unused, I want to append that ID to the CSV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moral of the story: Don't put in a exception handler if you don't expect it to skip reading the rest of the file. And don't just silence exceptions you don't understand.

Without the `IndexError` exception handler, your code doesn't actually work for your 'python produced' sample file, as the file started with a blank line. As a result you get an `IndexError` exception as the `row[0]` index fails. That means that the *rest* of the file is ignored, as you skip right to the `except IndexError` line, Python executes `pass` and that's it.

At the very least, your code could just avoid the `IndexError`:

```
for row in my_content:
    if not row:
        continue
```

and remove the `try:` / `except IndexError:` statements entirely. You can also move the exception handler closer to the actual code throwing the exception:

```
for row in my_content:
    try:
        Row = int(row[0])
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        print "Skipped a row, could not parse a number"
```

With that change in place, your sample files *both* work, e.g. `isThere` is set to `True`.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks so much for your help and patient explanations!  Lesson learned.